# in circle detection is there a better algorithm other than Hough Transform

Tags: matlab

i am doing a project in coin recognition . I used hough transform for circle detection. I would like to know is there any other circle detection algorithm that can replace hough transform, an algorithm that uses less storage space and less computation time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two related articles with Radon compared to Hough. This does not change the basic memory required from reviewing it but has a slightly different approach.

In the signal processing section they discuss types of transforms and their benefits and differences:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/470/whats-the-difference-between-the-hough-and-radon-transforms

Detecting the the differences and how Radon is useful is mentioned below:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2420/alternatives-to-hough-transform-for-detecting-a-grid-like-structure?lq=1

Here is a completely different approach that might be useful as well. It read like it would require more memory and processing time so doesn't answer the base question on having something better.
The circlet transform: A robust tool for detecting features with circular shapes
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300410002529

Hough Transforms have basically been around a while and dominate from the reading I've done.  I'm in my first semester Computer Vision course so someone with more history in CV might know more.

Comment: is discrete differential evolution suitable for coin recognition?